# Exception handling / suppression with higher order function

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have an application in a micro service architecture. This application is getting data from different sources and is getting a lot of different error-responses from the various of other applications. Some exceptions, like 404-Not found exceptions can be thrown and returned to the end-user, but other exceptions (bad requests, ++) can't and need to be suppressed by throwing some other exception.

However, I know this can be solved by `try-catch`ing the exceptions and moderating what to throw in that matter, but that would involve a lot of code.. sometimes I want to accept 4-5 different exceptions, while other times only 1-2 exceptions.

---

Anyhow.. I need some help making a higher order function. I want a function that takes one or more "accepted exceptions" as parameters (they're Runtime-exceptions) and throws only the approved exceptions in a `try-catch`.

This is what I have tried, **but can't seem to get the syntax right** (pseudo-code atm.). Any help is really appreciated.

```
  fun getData() {
    return supressExceptions(
        NotFoundException::class.java, 
        ForbiddenException::class.java, 
        AuthorizationException::class.java) {
      service.getData()
    }
  }

  private inline fun <T, X : RuntimeException> supressExceptions(vararg approvedException: Class<X>, block: () -> T): T =
      try {
        block()
      } catch (ex: Exception) {
        // Loop through the approved exceptions.
        // Throw the approved exception
        throw ex
        // ELSE: do something else if the exception is not approved.
      }
```

Comment: from the naming of the function I would have expected that you actually pass the exceptions to be suppressed to the function... ;-)

Comment: hmmm... from the solutions I see no one checks whether the given exception is an instance of the passed exception types, but rather check whether they have the same type... you may (or may not...) want to check if it is an actual instance instead... just in case someone derived a `NotFoundException` or similar ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the below what you're looking for?

```
private inline fun <T> supressExceptions(vararg approvedException: Class<out RuntimeException>, block: () -> T): T =
        try {
            block()
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            if (approvedException.contains(ex::class.java)) {
                // Approved exception
                throw ex
            }
            // ELSE: do something else if the exception is not approved.
            else throw Exception("Something else")
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll approve your answer. I did something similar.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by [`any`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/any.html):

```
  private inline fun <T, X : RuntimeException> supressExceptions(vararg approvedException: Class<X>,
      block: () -> T): T =
      try {
        block()
      } catch (ex: Exception) {
        when {
          approvedException.any { ex::class.java == it } -> throw ex
          else -> {
            throw SupressedException(ex)
          }
        }
      }
```

> **any**: Returns true if at least one entry matches the given predicate.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments: from the naming I would have expected that the suppressExceptions rather accepts a parameter of the exceptions to be suppressed.

I wonder whether you actually rather want to check whether a thrown exception is actually an instance of the given exception types, i.e. if also subclasses of the given types should be approved/suppressed or not.

In such a case I would rather use the following code:

```
inline fun <T> suppressAllExceptions(vararg exceptExceptions: Class<out Exception> = emptyArray(),
                                     block: () -> T) = try {
  block()
} catch (e: Exception) {
  throw if (exceptExceptions.any { it.isInstance(e) }) {
    e
  } else SuppressedException(e)
}
```

You would still use it the same way as you have shown:

```
suppressAllExceptions {
  throw IllegalStateException("i am suppressed soon")
}
suppressAllExceptions(IllegalStateException::class.java, 
                      IllegalArgumentException::class.java) {
  throw IllegalStateException("i am not suppressed")
}
class MyIllegalStateException : IllegalStateException()
suppressAllExceptions(IllegalStateException::class.java, 
                      IllegalArgumentException::class.java) {
  throw MyIllegalStateException("i am not suppressed neither")
}
```

The more I think of it: why do you approve different types of exceptions at different places? This doesn't sound right to me. You probably rather want to suppress all exceptions except some well-defined ones and in such a case you do not need such a generic function in the first place, but rather have one suppressing function that contains that well-defined list:

```
/**
 * Suppresses all exceptions except the well-defined ones: [NotFoundException], ...
 */
inline fun <T> suppressExceptions(block: () -> T) = try {
  block()
} catch (e: Exception) {
  throw when (e) {
    is NotFoundException,
    is ForbiddenException,
    // all the other well-defined non-suppressable types
    is AuthorizationException -> e
    else -> SuppressedException(e)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply. I liked your solution, but we can't "whitelist" well-defined exceptions. Some context: the application is an "orchestrator"-application which is fetching and posting data for several different apps. One error (lets say NotFound) from one service might be OK to send back to the user, but a 404-error from another service could mean "the orchestrator did something wrong" and therefor should return a internal server error to the user.

Comment: even if it is an orchestrator... I don't want to be the one having to keep that mapping up to date (e.g. which exception should pass through and which shouldn't...) ... and then you wire the path which service talks to which differently and then an exception passes through which shouldn't... or one is swallowed which should have passed .... I don't know... it sounds like trouble to me... ;-)

Comment: Valid point. Maybe we can do something about the exception handling and reconsider this solution. Thanks for great input